# How is different methods of a class changing a member's data different from a global variable

Tags: java, oop, global-variables

Say, I have a member variable called `i` and I'm changing it's value in three different methods in the class.

So, each time, the starting value of `i` is different? How is this different from having a global variable, which is a strong no-no, and frowned upon?

```
public class ChangingMember {
int i = 1;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ChangingMember obj = new ChangingMember();
    System.out.println(obj.i);
    obj.test();
    obj.test1();
    obj.test2();
    System.out.println(obj.i);
}

public void test() {
    i++;
}

public void test1() {
    i++;
}

public void test2() {
    i++;
}
```

}

Comment: It's different from a global variable because you can create another instance of `ChangingMember`, and its `i` field will be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need access to the object to call those methods. That means you have a clear dependency on it. It would need to be passed to any class using it. Only code that you explicitly give access to this object can change the variable. That is different from a global variable.

```
void foo(ChangeingMember member) { // <-- dependency
    member.test1();    
}

void bar() { // <-- no dependency
    SomeGlobal.someMethod();
}
```

If you create an object:

```
ChangingMember obj = new ChangingMember();
```

You will still control it's state. Only when you give some other code access to the object can the state be changed:

```
foo(obj); // Giving 'foo' access to 'obj'
```

But anything can access the global variable. There is no encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will always be the same because the variable is not static.

If you create a new object of ChangingMember class, the starting value of i will be the same(1). If you want it to always have the last value on new objects your have to make this property static.

static int i = 1;

Comment: `i++`, `++i`, and `i += 1` will all increment the value of `i` by 1.

Comment: Yes, you are right, i though we had to reasign the value!

Answer (score 0):

Since you use only one instance of the class you can modify its variable using their methods. To make the variable global or shared with other instances of that class you can add a `static` modifier.  So the code will output the same result

```
static int i = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ChangingMember obj = new ChangingMember();

    System.out.println(obj.i);

    new ChangingMember().test();
    new ChangingMember().test1();
    new ChangingMember().test2();

    System.out.println(obj.i);
}
```

Now if you remove `static` modifier the result will be different.

Answer (score 0):

**Value of all global variables assign at the initialization of class.**

Lets traverse through your code line by line.

> ```
>  ChangingMember obj = new ChangingMember();
> ```

Object created, now and values of all global variables assigned to the object(obj), which is 1.

> ```
>     obj.test();
> ```

test() is called by object, which performs incremental procedure of a variable i, which is already having value 1 in the scope of Object obj.

> ```
> public void test() {
>     i++;
> }
> ```
>
> ..and hence it will be incremented. Same applies to rest two methods.

Note: Please insist on using better [naming conventions](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions) while writing code.